# Tip - pass several parameters apex to lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a doubt. I need some paramethers in my lightning page, what is better?

- 3 Queries in apex. In lightning, callBack within callBack within callBack (the 3 parameters must be filled to operate between them).
- Apex return this 3paramethers with json.

Which is more optimal?

Comment: One request gets my vote but as side note Promises are nice way of handling multiple call backs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do a wrapper with the 3 parameters, and send in just one request. Because in each request you have the latency that is much less efficient. And many callbacks increases the complexity and is harder to maintain.

Comment: I like your wrapper. I had thought in a json, but wrapper is more easy :). Yeah, with the wrapper we can do several queries in a only request. Thanks